# Delphi: Missing Operator or Semicolon

Tags: delphi, operator-keyword

I am using Indy 10(TIdTcpServer) and I get the following error:

```
[DCC Error] MainForm.pas(88): E2066 Missing operator or semicolon
```

When trying to run this code:

```
procedure TForm1.SendMessage(Data: String; Client: Integer);
var
  List: TList;
  AContext: TIdContext;
begin
  List := idTcpServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  AContext(List[0]).Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Data);  // Line 88
end;
```

I cannot figure out what I am missing; any help?

Comment: It's nice you included the code, but since you didn't post much it would be nice to know which one is line 88 (and see the lines from 80 on that lead up to that line).

Comment: Oh sorry. I meant to put that. Line 88: 
    AContext(List[0]).Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Data);
 There are no other references to these; besides the code for connecting.

Comment: While I can't explain the error you're getting, your code is totally wrong. Change line 88 to be two new lines: `AContext := TIdContext(List[0]); AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Data);' instead.

Comment: Welp, that did it. Thank you for your help; simple mistake :P

Comment: I posted it as an answer, so it will maybe help future readers of this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While I can't explain the error you're getting, your code is totally wrong.

Change it to:

```
procedure TForm1.SendMessage(Data: String; Client: Integer);
var
  List: TList;
  AContext: TIdContext;
begin
  List := idTcpServer1.Contexts.LockList;
  AContext := TIdContext(List[0]);
  AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(Data);
end;
```

Your bad use of the typecast with a non-type may be confusing the compiler. If that doesn't solve it, please edit your question to add more code around what you've posted (the dozen or so lines before what you've posted would help).

Comment: FWIW the error comes from this: `AContext(List[0])`. `AContext` is a variable and must be followed by either a semicolon or an operator.